# Jasmine's spy doesn't work in image onload event

Tags: image, asynchronous, jasmine, onload, spy

I am using karma-jasmine and browserify to test Vue component. One method listen on image on load event. But the spy that called in the event handler didn't get the right result. Following snippets shows the error:

```
let spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy')
spy.and.returnValues({
  name: 'name'
})

describe('example tests', () => {
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    var img = new Image()
    img.onload = function() {
      console.log('2', spy())
      done()
    }
    img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100"
    console.log('1', spy())
  })
})
```

here we are, at position 1, the log shows 1, but at position 2, the log shows undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The `.and.returnValues` function you are chaining to the spy will only return the object specified once, [all subsequent calls to the spy will return undefined](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValues%3C/code%3E).

If you were to do the following:

```
let spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy')
spy.and.returnValues({
  name: 'name'},
 {name: 'name2'}
)

describe('example tests', () => {
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    var img = new Image()
    img.onload = function() {
    console.log('2', spy())
    done()
    }
    img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100"
    console.log('1', spy())
  })
})
```

You will find that the console will log "1 Object {name: "name"}" and then 2 Object {name: "name2"}.

If you want the spy to always return the same object you need to use `.and.returnValue` rather than `.and.returnValues`:

```
let spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy')
spy.and.returnValue({
  name: 'name'})

describe('example tests', () => {
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    var img = new Image()
    img.onload = function() {
    console.log('2', spy())
    done()
    }
    img.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100"
    console.log('1', spy())
  })
})
```